# Overloading Pandas operators

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to subclass a pandas Series and overload the operators, but cannot figure out why I'm getting a recursion error.
Minimally reproduceable example below:

```
import pandas as pd

class MySeries(pd.Series):

    def __mul__(self, other):
        print('hello!')
        return super().mul(other)

MySeries([1,2,3]) * 1
```

I get the following error:

```
hello!
...
hello!
  File "/home/jibi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 197, in flex_wrapper
    return op(self, other)
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __mul__
...
  File "/home/jibi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 197, in flex_wrapper
    return op(self, other)
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __mul__
packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 90, in get_op_result_name
    if isinstance(right, (ABCSeries, ABCIndex)):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Observations:

- the following don't seem to make a difference:

  - adding a `mul` method
  - adding a `__rmul__` method
  - adding the `_constructor` method (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures)
- The error only occurs when I multiply the subclassed instance by an integer, but all is well if I multiply it by a Series or another subclassed instance
- calling `MySeries([1,2,3]).mul(1)` also breaks. It doesn't break if I remove the `__mul__` method in `MySeries`.
- This happens with other operators (`__add__`, `__sub__`, etc)
- I can subclass a `DataFrame` and override the `__mul__` method with the exact same code and the `*` operator behaves as expected (i.e. this is only happening when I subclass a `Series`)

Been banging my head on the desk for a few hours now--any insight is appreciated! Thanks!

pandas version `1.4.3`; python `3.9.5`

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that `mul` and `__mul__` are two different functions in the `pd.Series`. The double underscore is mainly a convention in Python to represent private variables.

When you call `MySeries.__mul__`: first this results in a call of `super().mul(..)` whose internal logic is defined in pandas to call the `__mul__` function of `MySeries`, which in turn calls `super().mul(..)` and so on and so on... hence the infinite recursion.

The solution is to replace `super().mul(other)` with `super().__mul__(other)`

The following code gives the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

class MySeries(pd.Series):

    def __mul__(self, other):
        print('hello!')
        return super().__mul__(other)

MySeries([1,2,3]) * 2
```

Comment: _"The double underscore is mainly a convention in Python to represent private variables."_ Wrong: Double leading *and* trailing underscores indicate magic methods.

Comment: If it wasn't clear, `MySeries.mul()` also works because of this.